# 'float' object is not subscriptable - List Coding

Tags: python, list, floating-point, append

```
acumSubTotal = 0
acumIva = 0
acumTotalProd = 0

listatotalProd=[]
listasubTotal = []
listacodProducto= []
listanomProducto=[]
listacanProducto=[]
listavalUnitario=[]
listatipoIva=[]
N = int(input("Digite la cantidad de Artículos a facturar: "))

for item in range(N):
    i = item + 1
    listacodProducto.append(int(input(f"Digite el código del producto {item + 1}: ")))
    listanomProducto.append((input(f"Digite el nombre del producto {item + 1}: ")))
    listacanProducto.append(float(input(f"Digite la cantidad del producto {item + 1}: ")))
    listavalUnitario.append(float(input(f"Digite el valor unitario del producto {item + 1}: ")))
    listatipoIva.append(float(input(f"Tipo de IVA (que puede ser: 1: Exento de IVA, 2: Bienes, IVA 5%, 3: General, IVA 19%) del producto {item + 1}: ")))

    listasubTotal.append(listavalUnitario[item] * listacanProducto[item])

    if listatipoIva[item] == 1:
        listatipoIva = 0
    elif listatipoIva[item] == 2:
        listatipoIva = listasubTotal[item] * 0.05   
    else :
        listatipoIva = listasubTotal[item] * 0.19
   

    listatotalProd.append(listatipoIva[item] + listasubTotal[item])
```

I cannot find a reason for this problem. I'm just getting started and I can't figure out what is the error. Code's in spanish hope you don't mind. Help!!

The error is showing specifically on the last line under 'float' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: In your `if` blocks you set `listatipoIva` to a number, so it's no longer the list that you assigned earlier.

Comment: I suspect you meant to assign to `listatipoIva[item]`, not `listatipoIva`.

Comment: having lots of parallel lists is usually poor design. Things are easier if you have a single list of tuples or dictionaries, so that all the related data is kept together.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I cannot find a reason for this problem." Here are some hints for finding problems: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ It is also a good idea to start by *reading* and *trying to understand* the error message. For example, do you understand what line of code it refers to? Do you understand what "subscriptable" means? Do you understand what a `float object` is?

Comment: Next, after understanding the *described problem*, look at the code to see the *proximate cause*: which thing is being subscripted? Does it make sense to try to subscript there? Should that thing be a float at this point? If not, what should it be? Finally, work backwards to look for an *ultimate cause*: *why* is that thing a `float`, at that point in the code? When and where did that happen? Should that have happened? What should have happened instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are defining `listatipoIva` as a list but then in you if-statement you are doing

```
listatipoIva = some_number
```

When you try to access `listatipoIva[item]` at the end of you for loop the error you are seeing is because listatipoIva is no longer a subscriptable object.

Subscriptable objects are those that implement the `__getitem__()` method like: strings, lists, tuples, and dictionaries. NOT floats or ints.

You need to look into this structure:

```
    if listatipoIva[item] == 1:
        listatipoIva = 0
    elif listatipoIva[item] == 2:
        listatipoIva = listasubTotal[item] * 0.05   
    else :
        listatipoIva = listasubTotal[item] * 0.19
```

And figure out what you want to do. If I understand right, depending on the selected user input (1, 2 or 3) you want to operate on the  `listasubTotal` value. Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
     if listatipoIva[item] == 1:
        listasubTotal[item] = 0
    elif listatipoIva[item] == 2:
        listasubTotal[item] =* 0.05   
    else :
        listasubTotal[item] =* 0.19
```

That will change the value of listasubTotal[item] depending on the selected IVA option.

As a recommendation, to improve code readability use snake_case or if you really want to use camelCase use it consistently (`listaCanProducto` instead of `listacanProducto`)